# How can I pause/suspend a running valgrind (with callgrind) instance?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, suspend, profiling

I have some rather chunky piece of software being profiled via `valgrind --tool=callgrind MySoftware` (bash at Ubuntu 16.04 if it makes any difference). It was running overnight, but still hasn't finished. I'm happy to keep it running over another night, but I need my computer's full processing power now.

I had the idea of suspending the process and then resuming it tonight before leaving the computer. I pressed `Ctrl+Z` in the shell where it is running, but it's ignoring it happily - all I've got back was `^Z` in the terminal and more output from the app. It's still taking 100% of one of my cores.

I don't want to kill it and lose ~20 hours of computation. How can I temporarily pause it and then restart it again? Or at least temporarily assign it (near-) zero resources (less than just `nice`ing it)?